# How to plot a zero-one matrix that will look like scatter?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix of zeros and ones and I want to plot  the ones in their location in the matrix. So that it will look like the matrix but instead of ones a marker and instead of zeros  nothing.
Is there a function for doing this or I need to get the x and y for every one and then just do a simple scatter plot?
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 10):

Try the function `spy`, it plots a blue dot for every non-zero entry of a matrix.

Answer (score 3):

```
imagesc
```

is an approach for this that I find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to get coordinates of non-zero elements with FIND:

```
[x,y] = find(A);
scatter(x,y)
```

It's the same way as used by SPY, just with a little more control. In opposite to PLOT or SCATTER, SPY does not return points handle, which anyway can be retrieved by FINDOBJ.